# editable select not working proprerly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

need an help of using the editable select ....i have used many methods of jsfiddle ....but that doesnt work fine ....could some one help me out with this...i tried with these links such as https://github.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select and many more and we have also downloaded editable select plugins such as jquery-editable-select.js, jquery-editable-select.min.js,jquery-editable-select.css , jquery-editable-select.min.css

```js
$('#editable-select').editableSelect();
```

```html
<link href="//rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<select id="editable-select">
 <option>Alfa Romeo</option>
 <option selected>Audi</option>
 <option>BMW</option>
 <option>Citroen</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your tag links were wrong:

```js
$('#editable-select').editableSelect();
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="//rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<select id="editable-select">
 <option>Alfa Romeo</option>
 <option selected>Audi</option>
 <option>BMW</option>
 <option>Citroen</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can try Below code

```js
$('#editable-select').editableSelect();
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-editable-select@2.2.5/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-editable-select@2.2.5/dist/jquery-editable-select.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<select id="editable-select">
 <option>Alfa Romeo</option>
 <option selected>Audi</option>
 <option>BMW</option>
 <option>Citroen</option>
</select>
```

[To View in Fiddle Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/dhaval_123/7rmq6nj4/1/)